# Getting Exception "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" when trying to access oracle database through Entity Framework in Coded UI Test

Tags: .net, oracle, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, coded-ui-tests

I have created a Coded UI Test project with the following settings:
NuGet Packages Installed:
**EntityFramework 6.0.0 
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFrameWork 12.1.2400
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.1.2400**

Target Framework:.Net Framework **4.5.2**

When trying to access the oracle database through Entity Eramework 6.0.0, I get the exception below:

Result Message:

**Test method ExcelDBImplementation.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestOracleEntityFramework threw exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.**

However, when running a console application project or a unit test project with the same settings, it runs sucessfully. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Nuget packages for the Coded UI Test project but i still get the same exception.

Is there any difference in the Coded UI Test project that causes this difference in behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would work in unit test project, but not coded ui project.  However, I would caution you to make sure you're testing the right things with the right tests.  Coded UI tests are mainly for UI concerns.  It seems like you are also validating data which is typically a unit testing concern.  I would validate that the data is fetched correctly when a model action is called in a unit test and then make sure that the ui where the data is shown behaves correctly without validating the actual data, just the behaviors of the UI.

Comment: Hi, MPavlak. Thanks for the response, however, The coded UI Test project is used for testing the UI. Basically, the access to the database is used to get the data in order to test it against a value in the UI. it just seems based on the error, that for some unknown reason, the library fails to load, which until today I cant seem to figure out why.

Comment: Hey @Don, I would love to discuss further abt how to get test data without having to access your database.  Is there a way we can chat in a discussion or something?  I know it doesn't help your immediate problem of not being able to load dlls. What I would do then, is stand up a simple API that the test can call to get the data without needing to load the assembly.  Or, just grab some data out of the database and put it into a mocking class directly that just returns that data.  Please let me know if you're interested in further discussion around this.  I'm not sure about the libs not loading.

Comment: Sure, I am quite interested. Infact, we can start a discussion ASAP.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152449/coded-ui-chat

Comment: Sure that would be nice @MPavlak we shall have a further discussion.